# variavel não é 'salva' na programação

Tags: python

Estou aprendendo python e estou tentando programar uma plataforma pra jogar rpg de mesa

o meu intuito era montar um código que pegasse o nome de um personagem que seria colocado em um input e o adicionasse em um variavel, para que essa variavel fosse usada como o 'nome' do jogador.O problema é que meu código não 'salva' essa variavel.

eu estou usando uma ferramenta chamada PySimpleGUI para montar uma interface gráfica

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg 
from random import randint

class ScreenRecord():
def __init__(self):
    
    layoutRecord = [
        [sg.Text('Enter character name'),sg.Input(size=(15,0),key='character')],
        [sg.Button('Enter',key = 'Enter'),]
    ]

    self.window = sg.Window('teste-mecanica').layout(layoutRecord)
    self.button,self.values = self.window.Read()

    def Enter(event):
        character = self.values['character']
        tela = ScreenDice()
    
    while True :
        event,values = self.window.Read()
        if event is None:
            break
        if event in ['Enter']:
            Enter(event)

class ScreenDice(ScreenRecord):
def __init__(self):
    
    db = {'size':(12,2)}

    layoutDice = [
        
        [sg.Button('Roll D10',key= 'd10',**db),sg.Button('Roll D20',key='d20',**db)],
        
    ]
    self.window = sg.Window('teste-dado').layout(layoutDice)

    self.button,self.values = self.window.Read()

    def RollDice(event):
        print(character ,'received', randint(1,dice),'in the dice')
            

    while True :
        event , values = self.window.Read()
        if event is None:
            break
        if event in ['d10'] :
            dice = 10
            RollDice(event)
        if event in ['d20'] :
            dice = 20
            RollDice(event)
```

o terminal me retorna :

```
NameError: name 'character' is not defined
```

obs: é a minha primeira vez programando alguma coisa, perdoe-me se for uma pergunta idiota

Answer (score 0):

Esse  **character** não esta definida.
é só uma palavra solta.

como se tivesse querendo acessar algo que não existe.

exemplo de erro.

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jun 16 2020, 17:59:42) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> print(oi)  <==== tentando imprimir a palavra solta sem referencia
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'oi' is not defined

Eis sua lista.

```
DESCULPE A FALTA DE ATENÇÃO.
```

na classe **class ScreenRecord():** a uma variavel dentro de uma função

def Enter(event):
character = self.values['character']

E a outra classe que herda de ScreenRecord mas não esta chamando a variavel character da forma correta:

[herança](https://professormarcolan.com.br/como-utilizar-a-heranca-em-python/)

Comment: mas a linha    `` character = self.values['character']``    nao deveria resolver o problema ?

Comment: no Traceback  deu ruim, ponha um break point no inicio do código e vai percorrendo linha a linha, e veja o onde o erro ocorre se pq até o resultado é que a variavel não ta declarada e como estivesse consultado um palavra qualquer.

Answer (score 0):

sua classe **ScreenDice(ScreenRecord)** não esta referenciando o objeto da classe principal e por causa desse detalhe o "character" consta como não definida pois não foi chamada da forma esperada

Comment: a forma correta deveria ser :   class ScreenDice(ScreenRecord):
    def __init__(self):
        ScreenRecord.__init__(self)  ?            pois continuo recebendo o mesmo problema